# Openfire returns error 500 when retrieving privacy lists

Tags: xmpp, openfire, converse.js

I'm using `converse.js` and trying to work with privacy lists. I'm trying to send this IQ:

```
<body rid="2993056535" xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" sid="578oe88nm1">
    <iq from="alex3@ofb2" type="set" id="active1" xmlns="jabber:client">
        <query xmlns="jabber:iq:privacy"/>
    </iq>
</body>
```

This is what server returns me:

```
<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" ack="2993056535">
    <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="active1" to="alex3@ofb2/converse.js-90734653">
        <query xmlns="jabber:iq:privacy"/>
        <error code="500" type="wait">
            <internal-server-error xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
        </error>
    </iq>
</body>
```

In the server logs I see this exception:

```
2016.02.19 12:49:00 org.jivesoftware.openfire.handler.IQHandler - Internal server error
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.handler.IQPrivacyHandler.handleIQ(IQPrivacyHandler.java:120)
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.handler.IQHandler.process(IQHandler.java:66)
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.IQRouter.handle(IQRouter.java:372)
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.IQRouter.route(IQRouter.java:115)
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.PacketRouterImpl.route(PacketRouterImpl.java:78)
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.SessionPacketRouter.route(SessionPacketRouter.java:108)
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.SessionPacketRouter.route(SessionPacketRouter.java:67)
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSession.sendPendingPackets(HttpSession.java:639)
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSession$HttpPacketSender.run(HttpSession.java:1270)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Is there anything in the logs of the Openfire server?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UG9yJnHA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace [points to these lines](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire/blob/fe5c66ce9356274e4680bde83061d17828005d56/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/handler/IQPrivacyHandler.java#L118-L120):

```java
// Privacy list handling (create/edit/delete)
Element list = child.element("list");
String listName = list.attributeValue("name");
```

That is, it looks for a child element `<list>`, and crashes when it can't find it.

So why does it look for that?  It turns out that this is the branch it takes if the IQ has type `set` (and neither a `<default>` nor `<active>` child element).  However, as described in [XEP-0016](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0016.html#protocol-retrieve), to get the names of existing privacy lists you need to send an IQ with type `get` instead.  Your request should look like this instead:

```xml
<iq from='romeo@example.net/orchard' type='get' id='getlist1'>
<query xmlns='jabber:iq:privacy'/>
</iq>
```